# Не получается вывести значение поля из таблицы

Tags: php

Вопрос, конечно, кому-то покажется легким, но у меня никак не получается удалить запись из таблицы не вводя `id` записи, по идее при нажатии `delete record`, должно возвращать `id` т.е. указывает на запись которую собираюсь удалить. Вот код:

```
<?php
require_once 'inc/init.inc.php';
if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) {
try
{   
    $BookID=$_POST['BookID'];
    $book->deleterecord($BookID);

    $result =$book->allbook();
    $count=count($result);
    if ($count>0)
    {
     $edit=true;

     displaybook($result, $edit);
    }
     else exit ("<br>There are no books to view!");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{

   echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage().'</p>';
}
}
else {
$BookID = $_GET['BookID'];
try
 {

    $book = $book->onebook($BookID);
    $BookID= $book['BookID'];
    $Category = $book['Category'];
    $Title= $book['Title'];
    $Author=$book['Author'];
    $Publisher=$book['Publisher'];
    $Synopsis=$book['Synopsis'];
    $PageNum=$book['PageNum'];
    $PubDate=$book['PubDate'];
    $ReleaseDate=$book['ReleaseDate'];
    $Price=$book['Price'];
 }
 catch (PDOException $e)
 {
   echo '<br>PDO Exception Caught.';
   echo 'Error with the database: <br>';
   echo 'SQL Query: ', $sql;
   echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage().'</p>';
 }
?>
</p>


<form action = "" method = "post" id = "bookentry" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset><legend>Delete a Book Record</legend>
       <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="BookID" class="col-sm-2 control-label">BookID</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="BookID" id="BookID"  class="form-control"  maxlength="9" readonly value = "<?php echo $BookID ?>">
       </div>
     </div>

         <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="Category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="Category" id="Category"   class="form-control"  value = "<?php echo $Category; ?>">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="Title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title"  class="form-control"    readonly value = "<?php echo $Title; ?>">
       </div>
     </div>


     <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="Author" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="Author" id="Author"   class="form-control"   readonly value = "<?php echo $Author; ?>">
       </div>
     </div>


         <div class ="form-group">
          <label for="pub" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Publisher</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select name = "pub" id="pub" disabled = "disabled"class="form-control" >

        <?php
        foreach($publishers as $publisher)
        {
          if ($pub==$publisher)
          {
           echo"<option selected = 'selected' value ='$pub'>" . "$pub</option>\n";
          }
           else {
             echo"<option value = '$publisher'>$publisher</option>\n";
          }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div></div>

     <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="Synopsis" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Synopsis</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="Synopsis" id="Synopsis" class="form-control" readonly value = "<?php echo $Synopsis; ?>">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="PageNum" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PageNum</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="PageNum" id="PageNum"  class="form-control" readonly value = "<?php echo $PageNum;?>">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="PubDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PubDate</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="PubDate" id="PubDate" class="form-control"  readonly value = "<?php echo $PubDate; ?>">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="ReleaseDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ReleaseDate</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="ReleaseDate" id="ReleaseDate"   class="form-control" readonly value = "<?php echo $ReleaseDate; ?>">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class ="form-group">
       <label for="Price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label></td>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="Price" id="Price" class="form-control"  readonly value = "<?php echo $Price; ?>">
       </div></div>



<div class="buttonarea">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete Book  Record" name = "Submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this recor?')">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="history.back();" >

         </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <?php
}?>
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нажатии кнопки "Delete record" выполняется отправка формы с данными, которыми эта форма заполнена.

В вашем случае значение для поля BookID берется либо из POST-параметра, если была нажата кнопка Sumbit, либо из GET-параметра в противном случае.

Т.е. чтобы было подставлено значение в поле BookID для вашего кода этот параметр необходимо первоначально передавать в GET-параметре запроса, например http://localhost/myform.php?BookID=123

Чтобы разобраться в логике работы своего кода, можете ставить контрольные точки в разных местах кода и проверять результат. В самом простом случае после строчки 7 добавьте

```
die("Point1: {$_POST['BookID']}");
```

после строчки 26

```
die("Point2: {$_GET['BookID']}");
```

и увидите, в какое место зашел интерпретатор и какое значение имеет переменная.

Comment: спасибо за детальный ответ!!!!